# How to bring custom fields created under inherited process in Azure DevOps Queries

Tags: azure-devops, scrum

I created a inherited process under inherited Scrum process (like 'X-Scrum') and added new fields like the below,

1. X.Original Estimate (Decimal)
2. X.Completed work (Decimal)
3. X.Remaining work (Decimal)

This is successfully done and reflected in the task screen.

Issue/ Help required:

I'm not able to bring those three fields into QUERIES, as I would like to extract all product backlog item, tasks and related custom fields.

Can someone help me on how to bring the custom fields into the queries.

Comment: Does this help? See: 
Add or remove columns - Azure Boards
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/set-column-options

Answer (score 0):

Some special characters are prohibited for the Definition name of the custom field. If you add a new field with one of them(eg. `.`,`()`), you will get below error.

[image]

However you can change the **Label** of the field in the **Layout** section, which will be displayed in the task screen

[image]

[image]

In the QUERIES, only the **Definition** Name is showing up in the **fields**

[image]

[image]

So I guess you just changed the **Layout Label** of the custom field as `X.Original Estimate (Decimal)`. But the **Definition Name** of the custom field is not `X.Original Estimate (Decimal)`. Yon need to check what is **Name** for the field in **Definition** section. The Queries will reflect this Name.